# Doesn't meta give out too much information about the working of this site?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

I recently found a question about `serial voting` and `reversal`, and I felt that the answer was giving out too much information (possibly sensitive information).

It spoke about a script and gave out the exact time at which this script runs to check for spam voting, etc. Isn't information like this really sensitive considering the security of a site (speaking about a script)?

People may use these ideas and information to manipulate the site content or may be even hack it.

In this case, the person may block the script (maybe, since even the time at which the script runs was given out).

In that case, shouldn't the answers be censored if it gives out fragile information?

And how come users who are answering know too much about the programs and the scripts involved in this site? Are developers also taking part in meta?

Are there members of the developing/programming team of the site on meta (since they seem to know a lot about the scripts and stuff)?

Comment: The reversal script runs on the server not on user's PCs. You can't block it unless you're a stack employee with rights to do so. Developers do take part, that's rather the point of meta.

Comment: To answer your last few questions - yes, developers/programmers participate in Meta. I am one of those.

Comment: That's great @Oded .Thanks for this awesome site!

Comment: @MathewsMathai you should thank Jeff and Joel for the original thing, Oded is "just" helping to keep the cake whole and warm. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard
True that!I will always be thankful to Jeff and Joel.But you are all part of the reason why this site is so real,active and amazing!!

Comment: @Mathews oh, now I'm blushing. :-D

Comment: @ShadowWizard  Well you have a right to.You earned it!! ;)
You people are doing an amazing job out there.You won't believe,I have almost stopped visiting other sites related to programming and I never found a single bug on stackoverflow.The way the system and the moderators co-operate with the users are amazing.KEEP IT UP!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, even the greatest hackers can't hack Stack Exchange just because they know there is a script running at 3 AM that is reversing serial upvotes or downvotes.

I suppose you mean hacker can potentially use SQL Injection attack, injecting SQL to steal sensitive database information or just wreak havoc on the data. I agree that knowing the table names, field names, etc, indeed helps such attack,  but those names are public knowledge for years, in [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/).

Thing is, Stack Exchange is fully protected against SQL Injection attacks. I'm sure people tried, still trying, and will always try, to use SQL Injection against Stack Exchange, in any available form. And in all the years Stack Exchange exists, nobody ever succeeded, as far as I know.

Comment: There hasn't been even one successful attack?

Comment: @MathewsMathai not as result of SQL Injection, as far as I know. What I do know about, is a user who changed his IP address to appear as 127.0.0.1 then he gained admin powers as a result, and could possibly take everything down. He just sent email to the team, it was fixed, and he's now in the [Hall of Fame](http://stackexchange.com/about/security) (I believe he's the one listed for 2009-2010) - don't know about the others listed there, but pretty sure they found other ways to "hack", not via SQL Injection.

Comment: @MathewsMathai [read this](http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2012/11/anatomy-of-attack-how-i-hacked.html).

Comment: Wow...I am learning a lot new things about Stack Exchange.This place is amazing!

Comment: @MathewsMathai cheers, just don't let the downvotes sting too much, nothing is personal. (in this specific question for example, people disagree with the idea that exposing such information put SE at risk, and in Meta downvotes are a way to express such disagreement.)

Comment: Let me add that security by obscurity is not the best strategy. Be as open as possible to find weaknesses in your system.

Comment: @ShadowWizard   I agree.I am happy about the fact that there are people to help.

Comment: @MathewsMathai no problem, and one last thing, worth to mention that when it comes to actual sensitive information being posted, the staff is taking instant action and delete any trace of that information - I know this for sure as I was part of such thing once, and was glad to see such action taken.

Comment: There were some successful attacks (fortunately friendly) early on, during the private beta of the very first site, Stack Overflow. Jeff Atwood made an account of it (on the podcast?).

Comment: @Peter true, I remember reading about it, but didn't mention since it all happened when Stack Overflow was still wide open for such attacks, on purpose. (And looks like it worked well. :))

Comment: @ShadowWizard Why `on purpose`? Was it to check the extend of harm an attack could cause?

Comment: @Mathews From what I remember when reading about it then yes, they also invited people to try their best at hacking and DDoS-ing to check how it's all working under pressure. Might be mixing with something else so to know for sure you better read Jeff blog yourself, but to me it makes sense.

Comment: @ShadowWizard That means this site is designed on the base of actual attacks which probably made it this strong and secure.This seems so like a dream to me.!